# Different Colours for highlight in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

In the preamble, these are the codes that I've kinda modified from the findings here. I am trying to enable different colours in the highlight style option, but to no avail.

Error: ! Illegal parameter number in definition of `\pgfkeys@temp`.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parselines}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
\newcommand\setrow[9]{
  \setcounter{col}{1}
  \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {
    \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}
    \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}
    \node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}}] at (\x, \y) {\n};
    \stepcounter{col}
  }
  \stepcounter{row}
}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% Some customizable styles
\tikzset {
  every highlight/.style = {color=#3, opacity=0.3},
  %highlight1/.style = {gray, opacity=0.3}
  digit/.style = { minimum height = 5mm, minimum width=5mm, anchor=center },
}
\def\highlightcell#1#2#3{
\fill[every highlight] (#1-#2.north west) rectangle (#1-#2.south east);
}
```

Somewhere in the document, I am trying to draw this picture.. With some cells highlighted in cyan, some in gray. Currently, I am able to colour it in one colour only. Here's my attempt to colour it in 2 or more colours.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.55]
\begin{scope}
\draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
\draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

\setcounter{row}{1}
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

% Highlight some cells
\highlightcell{1}{1}{cyan}
\highlightcell{1}{4}{cyan}
\highlightcell{2}{7}{cyan}
\highlightcell{2}{1}{cyan}
\highlightcell{3}{1}{gray}
\highlightcell{3}{4}{gray}
\highlightcell{3}{7}{gray}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Not sure if anyone could give me some guidiance?

Comment: Try `every highlight/.style = {color=#1, opacity=0.3},` and `\fill[every highlight=#3] (#1-#2.north west) rectangle (#1-#2.south east);`.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your reply. Should it be color=#3 instead? :) In addition, can I ask how should I include #3 in the document body itself. 

is it still \highlightcell{3}{7}{gray}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key handler `.style` has only one parameter so you can not use the third (see [`pgfkeys` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) page 887). Therefore you should define the style as:

```
\tikzset {
    every highlight/.style = {color=#1, opacity=0.3},
    %highlight1/.style = {gray, opacity=0.3}
    digit/.style = { minimum height = 5mm, minimum width=5mm, anchor=center },
}
```

By the way, if you wanted to have a style with several parameters you could use `.style n args` (see page 888).

Then you must pass an argument to that parameter:

```
\newcommand{\highlightcell}[3]{%
    \fill[every highlight=#3] (#1-#2.north west) rectangle (#1-#2.south east);
}
```

I have replaced `\def` with `\newcommand` because `\newcommand` checks that you do not override an existing macro by mistake and you do not use `\def`'s power here.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{col}
\newcommand{\setrow}[9]{%
    \setcounter{col}{1}%
    \foreach \n in {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9} {%
        \edef\x{\value{col} - 0.5}%
        \edef\y{9.5 - \value{row}}%
        \node[digit,name={\arabic{row}-\arabic{col}}] at (\x, \y) {\n};%
        \stepcounter{col}%
    }%
    \stepcounter{row}%
}

% Some customizable styles
\tikzset {
    every highlight/.style = {color=#1, opacity=0.3},
    %highlight1/.style = {gray, opacity=0.3}
    digit/.style = { minimum height = 5mm, minimum width=5mm, anchor=center },
}
\newcommand{\highlightcell}[3]{%
    \fill[every highlight=#3] (#1-#2.north west) rectangle (#1-#2.south east);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.55]
\draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
\draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3);

\setcounter{row}{1}
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }
\setrow { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }  { }{ }{ }

% Highlight some cells
\highlightcell{1}{1}{cyan}
\highlightcell{1}{4}{cyan}
\highlightcell{2}{7}{cyan}
\highlightcell{2}{1}{cyan}
\highlightcell{3}{1}{gray}
\highlightcell{3}{4}{gray}
\highlightcell{3}{7}{gray}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

If no contents has to be added to cells, previous code can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

% Some customizable styles
\tikzset {
    every highlight/.style = {color=#1, opacity=0.3},
}
\newcommand{\highlightcell}[3]{%
    \fill[every highlight=#3] ({(#2-1)},{(9-#1)}) rectangle ++(1,1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.55]
\draw (0, 0) grid (9, 9);
\draw[very thick, scale=3] (0, 0) grid (3, 3) (0,0) rectangle (3,3);

% Highlight some cells
\highlightcell{1}{1}{cyan}
\highlightcell{1}{4}{cyan}
\highlightcell{2}{7}{cyan}
\highlightcell{2}{1}{cyan}
\highlightcell{3}{1}{gray}
\highlightcell{3}{4}{gray}
\highlightcell{3}{7}{gray}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]